# Dockerfile for an npm project

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I'm trying to add a docker-compose setup for the [crates.io](https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io) project. The current file for the npm piece is as follows:

```
FROM node:8.4
ENV npm_config_global true
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
```

And it's all fine and good but when I try to build it, all it does is:

```
Building frontend
Step 1/4 : FROM node:8.4
 ---> 6f6ffe2a1302
Step 2/4 : ENV npm_config_global true
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 868e1aec7aac
Step 3/4 : COPY package.json ./
 ---> 3846f64854e0
Removing intermediate container a1dea9f3f3a2
Step 4/4 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 18b3f1003133
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@5.3.0
npm info using node@v8.4.0
npm info lifecycle cargo@0.0.0~preinstall: cargo@0.0.0
npm info linkStuff cargo@0.0.0
npm info lifecycle cargo@0.0.0~install: cargo@0.0.0
npm info lifecycle cargo@0.0.0~postinstall: cargo@0.0.0
+ cargo@0.0.0
added 1 package in 0.23s
npm info ok 
 ---> 6785fa0a2b21
Removing intermediate container 18b3f1003133
Successfully built 6785fa0a2b21
Successfully tagged cratesio_frontend:latest
```

So none of the `devDependencies` are installed at all. What am I missing here? Is there some other parameter I should add?

I've already tried to run it with `--only=dev` and it doesn't work either.

Running it without copying `package-lock.json` also causes the same thing:

```
Building frontend
Step 1/4 : FROM node:8.4
 ---> 6f6ffe2a1302
Step 2/4 : ENV npm_config_global true
 ---> Running in b77c06987f48
 ---> f52a6255ea31
Removing intermediate container b77c06987f48
Step 3/4 : COPY package.json ./
 ---> 26f4c713399a
Removing intermediate container 27d6fe45b3be
Step 4/4 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 58d4bd0e8f75
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@5.3.0
npm info using node@v8.4.0
npm info lifecycle cargo@0.0.0~preinstall: cargo@0.0.0
npm info linkStuff cargo@0.0.0
npm info lifecycle cargo@0.0.0~install: cargo@0.0.0
npm info lifecycle cargo@0.0.0~postinstall: cargo@0.0.0
+ cargo@0.0.0
added 1 package in 0.207s
npm info ok 
 ---> 39f68ccde408
Removing intermediate container 58d4bd0e8f75
Successfully built 39f68ccde408
Successfully tagged cratesio_frontend:latest
```

Comment: Why are you setting `npm_config_global`?

Comment: Remove `ENV npm_config_global true` also change `COPY package.json package-lock.json ./` to `COPY package.json .`

Comment: @Ryan because this is a base image, i need all of these packages available so I can run commands in them without having to call `npm install` again. Is there another way to make these packages available other than using `npm_config_global` ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I can't just remove it, this is a base image, I need the packages to be installed in the machine.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares, i am just asking not to copy `package-lock.json` not removing the whole thing

Comment: No change, I need the packages to be installed globally as commands run in this base machine need all packages to be in place already.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares: Run the commands with `node_modules/.bin` in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your `package-lock.json` and `package.json` files for devDependency. As I see from log file you install `cargo` package as devDependency.
2. Your Dockerfile and log contradict each other. Please check what Dockerfile you use during build.

**Details Dockerfile:**

- Line 4 in Dockerfile is `RUN npm install`
- Line 5 in Dockerfile doesn't exist.

**Details Logs:**

```
Step 4/5 : RUN npm install --only=dev
...
Step 5/5 : RUN npm install
...
```